# Lambda vs. manually inlined code changes GCC's optimizer behavior

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, lambda

The following code:

```
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<int> rng;

int main()
{
  auto is_even=[](int x){return x%2==0;};
  int res=0;
  for(int x:rng){
    if(is_even(x))res+=x;
  }

  return res;
}
```

is optimized by GCC 11.1 ([link to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WcYsE8vaf)) in a very different way than:

```
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<int> rng;

int main()
{
  int res=0;
  for(int x:rng){
    if(x%2==0)res+=x;
  }

return res;
}
```

([Link to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3bKddx6e5).) Besides, the second version (where the lambda has been replaced by direct, manual injection of its body in the place of call), is much faster than the first one.

Is this a GCC bug?

Comment: Looking at the resulting assembly, the version with a lambda is not getting auto-vectorized, so the second version being faster makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Here's a side-by-side directly in godbolt, btw: https://godbolt.org/z/aYq5Gx3P8

Comment: Yep, but why is GCC not vectorizing with the lambda?

Comment: Clang appears to vectorise both versions, see: https://godbolt.org/z/Txb4scMo4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quirk of the code generation. There is no reason why the lambda version shouldn't be vectorized. In fact, [clang vectorizes it](https://godbolt.org/z/sv5qErqeM) as-is. If you specify return type as `int`, [GCC vectorizes it](https://godbolt.org/z/v78G63G9K) too:

```
auto is_even = [](int x) -> int { return x % 2 == 0; };
```

If you use `std::accumulate`, it's also [vectorized](https://godbolt.org/z/GW4o1cGjG). You can report this to GCC so they can fix it.

Comment: >You can report this to GCC so they can fix it.
Unfortunately GCC Bugzilla account creation is restricted, and manual requests to gcc-bugzilla-account-request@gcc.gnu.org are blocked, too.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a vectorized integral modulo operation in the x64 architecture. This means that the code by itself is not inherently vectorizable, and needs to be transformed beforehand before that can be done.

You can see the vectorization working just fine in both cases in the much easier case where a SIMD-friendly evenness test is used: https://godbolt.org/z/hc5ffbePY

So if anything, it could be argued that GCC managing to vectorize the inlined version at all, and clang inlining both of them, is actually pretty impressive.

That being said, since we know for a fact that GCC is capable of performing that transformation, it would appear that it is only performed before inlining happens, which is unfortunate, and probably deserves being brought up to the maintainer's attention.

Comment: Using `std::accumulate` with a lambda generates vectorized code. So, I don't think it's a problem with lambdas https://godbolt.org/z/GW4o1cGjG

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's not really an apples to oranges comparison here. The accumulate lambda is very different from the one in OP's question.

Comment: See my answer: Just changing return type from `bool` to `int` in OP's code causes GCC to vectorize it. You know what they say: When in doubt, replace `bool` with `int` :-)